# Rails simple form: Move font awesome icon next to input field

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, simple-form, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using the bootstrap datepicker plugin for two input fields inside a simple form:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
     <div class="form-group" id="datepickerContainer">
       <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
       <%= f.label "From" %>
       <%= f.input :from, :as => :string, label: false, :input_html => { :class => "datepicker", :id=>"datepickerContainer" } %>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6">
     <div class="form-group" id="datepickerContainer">
        <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
        <%= f.label "Until" %>
        <%= f.input :until, :as => :string, label: false, :input_html => { :class => "datepicker" } %>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Currently as you can see above I have a font awesome icon next to each label... and I would like to move the awesome icon next to the each input like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

So I'm doing this:

```
 <div class="input-group mb-3">
     <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
      </div>
        <%= f.input :from, :as => :string, label: false, :input_html => { :class => "datepicker", :id=>"datepickerContainer" } %>
 </div>
```

But I'm getting this results:

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Its everything fine with your code, and when I run the code, looks also fine, it wont show the way on your picture. try to run your code with another browser and let as know if its still the same

Comment: Thanks for the reply @hamid.... I'm using safari and I just tested the code on a chrome browser, but I'm gating the same wrong result. I have nooo idea why this happening!

Comment: could you give us more codes? or upload it on codepen.io or https://jsfiddle.net/ ? so we can findout the problem.

Comment: Btw the same thing happens even if I strip down the form only to that field.. the same wrong result I mean

Comment: Basically that's all I have... the form and the fields inside

Comment: Another thing I forgot is is the form `<%= simple_form_for @post, url: new_post_path, method: :post, validate: true do |f| %>`